# Issue with update the Wordpress Database

Tags: php, wordpress

Tried to update our Wordpress site database for the new version and I am getting the following error;

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method wpdb::esc_like() in /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/schema.php on line 564
```

The code on the schema.php is the latest version?? Not sure why it is throwing an error?

Comment: there are some good suggestions to resolve this issue (or avoid it happening) in [this wordpress support thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgraded-to-27-now-cant-log-in)...

Comment: Looking pure at the error from the PHP perspective, the script is calling the method wpdb::esc_like() that cannot be found. Does schema.php includes wp-includes/wp-db.php where the class is defined and is this file up to date? The method is introduced as of version 4.0 of WordPress.

Comment: Thank you Barry, Some how the wp-db.php had been reverted to a previous version and was causing issues.